# How to interpret the rvecs with aruco

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I have read some of your articles and they have helped me a lot to know the ins and outs of computer vision.

I have a question about a vision issue and I would like to consult with you to see if you can answer me. I have calibrated my camera, and using the aruco library I try to obtain the position of them with:

```
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250) ###
    parameters =  aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(img, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)
    if ids is not None:
        ids = self.__filteringWithOurList(ids, corners)
    localPositions = {}
    if ids is not None and len(ids.tolist()) > 0:
        rvec, tvec, object_points = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, self.camera_matrix, self.dist_coeffs)
```

My question comes in relation to that last line: the tvec (the vector of tranlation) I get it and it gives me good results regarding the position X, Y, Z of the aruco with respect to the camera, but with the rvec I do not have clear what I get.

What I would like to obtain are the navigation angles (pitch, roll and yaw) with respect to the camera, but what comes out there I do not understand. I know it's in radians, so I've transformed it into degrees, but I still can not interpret it.

What kind of rotation does it give me? How do I interpret it?

Thank you very much